# Use of the expression "Stop it! You are too cute"

Tags: meaning-in-context

In what context would you use "stop it!! you are too cute"?
Isn't that negative to say "stop it!! first?
Is there a degree or a connotation to it? (i.e, flirty, embarrassed, flattered, etc)

There are two contexts.

- romantic — a girl saying to a guy "Stop it! This is too much" but she's not annoyed.
- "stop it!! This is too cute" about a kid doing something cute.

I don't understand why you need the "stop it".

Comment: I would say it depends on the context and tone of voice.

Comment: You used a [[tag:meaning-in-context]] tag, but you haven't provided context.

Comment: “Stop it! You're too much/cute” sounds like a Tyler Oakley quote. This kind of humorous exaggeration is exceedingly common in the variety of Internet-speak used by YouTubers and their followers (similar to slang expressions like “bae”, “I've lost the ability to even”, “slay mamma”, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

In either case "Stop it!" conveys the idea that the cuteness (or other emotion inspired) is so overwhelming it is painful --it is hurting the heart of the person who experiences it.  It should generally be understood as a comic exaggeration of the situation.

As I understand it, the Japanese actually have a single word *kawaii* that conveys the entire concept of painful cuteness.  In English, however, we need a few more words to express the same experience.