# Usage of 'Ohh stop it, you!'

Tags: meaning, expressions, phrase-usage

Heard it quite a few times in television series episodes but find it hard to use it in real life. I have found this question '[Use of the expression "Stop it! You are too cute"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/194569/use-of-the-expression-stop-it-you-are-too-cute)' which I think is similar but was closed for being too broad and it has only one answer and it doesn't give the context when we could say something like that.

- What does it mean?
- Where and when and why exactly do we use it?

**EDIT**: One of the memes which I found is "https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3pm9.jpg" where they use this phrase. Just a quick google search result.
One more gif which I found was http://angpal.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/oh-you.gif Not sure if it helps the cause though

Comment: I'm afraid this may be closed as an even broader question than the one you linked to. Unless you provide a specific example and/or more context, that is. Why not find a script to the episode you watched and link to it?

Comment: @A.P. I don't remember any soap precisely now but I appended an image here. Hope it's better now.

Answer (score 5):

Typically, the phrase is meant to convey **an attitude of modesty and humble gratitude.**

Example:

*Guy: You've outdone yourself, Gretchen. This dinner is out of this world.*

*Gretchen: Oh stop it, you. You're too kind.*

The meme you linked to expresses the same sentiments, but the context is ironic or absurd most of the time.

Comment: It can also be used, of course, in the literal sense -- stop doing what you're doing.  In such a case, though, the tone of voice would be more abrupt and imperative.

Comment: I would say it is used especially in cases where the compliment is higher than the receiver thinks he/she deserves, and so the receiver is uncomfortable saying just “Thank you” (which implies the compliment is reasonable).  So, for example, if someone says, “That dinner was great!” the reply might be “Thank you” whereas “That dinner was amazing!” might be answered with “You’re too kind,” and “That’s the best dinner I’ve ever had in my life!” (overblown) would get you a “Oh, stop!” (with “You’re too kind” implied if not stated outright). Said in a silly tone because the purpose is to save face.